# methods to check https certificates

Tags: certificates, fingerprinting, certificate-transparency

I have a basic question regarding fingerprints of https certificates, the specific case I wanted to check being my online banking service. With firefox on linux, I can visit the specific web page and then click on the green lock and go to inspect the certificate, more precisely I can look at its SHA-256 fingerprint. If I now want to compare it with [this service](https://transparencyreport.google.com/https/certificates) it seems to me I cannot find the same SHA-256 fingerprint there, or at least not in the same format, so what to check? also, is there a simple shell script that automates the previous check that I did with firefox, somethin like `curl https... | sha256sum`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect www.security.us.hsbc.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509  -noout -fingerprint -sha256
```

The output should look like this:

```
$ echo -n | openssl s_client -connect www.security.us.hsbc.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509  -noout -fingerprint -sha256
SHA256 Fingerprint=2B:53:3C:29:EF:1E:DD:62:5A:A0:2A:D6:45:99:3C:6E:3F:6E:85:02:F5:D9:1A:85:8B:43:4E:82:90:D9:9C:65
```

Notice that the SHA256 fingerprint matches the screen shot below taken from Firefox

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. indeed it works on google.com, but when it try it on https://www.security.us.hsbc.com/gsa/SECURITY_LOGON_PAGE/ with or without the https : // www stuff or cutting from gsa/.., then I get: unable to load certificate
140652896214976:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE. do you know what i'm missing?

Comment: It doesn't seem like that subdomain exists `$ host security.us.hsbc.com/
Host security.us.hsbc.com/ not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: also, certificates are bound to domains and subdomains, you should not include anything after the .com or other TLD

Comment: Ok, I understand what you say, but still firefox gives a certificate fingerprint for that page that is different than us.hsbc.com. if i click on the link i provided indeed it gives error, but if i access it by going first to https://www.us.hsbc.com/1/2/home/personal-banking and then click log on button, that't the certificate i'd like to check

Comment: btw the script output seems to be 2/3 in length of sha256 fingerprint that i get from firefox, is it a different format?

Comment: you omitted the `https://` part. going to www.security.us.hsbc.com does not work while https://www.security.us.hsbc.com does

Comment: if i substitute what you write as `<your web site>` with `https://www.security.us.hsbc.com` i get an error, don't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66353/discussion-between-jj-p-and-mikeschem).

Comment: A related question: how can I compare the result shown above (and in firefox) with the serial number shown by the service I linked, say in the form `Serial number
5E:B9:CB:83:5F:9A:71:A1:E6:78:33:0A:B2:C7:D7:0D`

Comment: or if you want: how can i check sha256 from google/transparency report?

Comment: Please open a new question and link I'll post an answer there

Comment: sure, it is already there: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170330/compare-sha-256-fingerpirnt-of-certificate-with-google-transparency-report